# SQLAlchemy Bakery -Function expects a certain array size

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a strange issue in my Python project. It uses SQLAlchemy and Bakery to have prepared queries. I have a function that takes the connection (db), bakery, and an array of objects.

This function is called several times by an other function in a for loop and here is my issue (at least what I understand):

- Let's assume that the first time it receives an array with two elements.
- The next time it is called the function will also expect an array with two elements

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
def cpe_filter(db, bakery, iterable):
    cpes = []

    try:
        query  = bakery(lambda s: s.query(Cpe))
        query += lambda y: y.filter(
            sa.or_(*[
                Cpe.cpe.like(sa.bindparam('cpe_{}'.format(i)))
                for i, _ in enumerate(iterable)
            ])
        )
        query += lambda y: y.filter_by(active=sa.bindparam('active'))

        cpes = query(db).params(active=True,
                                **{'cpe_{}'.format(i): e for i, e in enumerate(iterable)}) \
                        .all()
    except NoResultFound:
        log.info("Found no CPE matching list {}.".format(iterable))
```

If the next array is smaller than the previous, I get this kind of error ([Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/sHp744ic)):

```
[2018-12-17 16:35:16 - INFO/sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:1151] SELECT cpe.id AS cpe_id, cpe.active AS cpe_active, cpe.date_created AS cpe_date_created, cpe.timestamp AS cpe_timestamp, cpe.cpe_part_id AS cpe_cpe_part_id, cpe.device_id AS cpe_device_id, cpe.cpe AS cpe_cpe, cpe.match_nvd AS cpe_match_nvd
FROM cpe
WHERE (cpe.cpe LIKE %(cpe_0)s OR cpe.cpe LIKE %(cpe_1)s OR cpe.cpe LIKE %(cpe_2)s) AND cpe.active = %(active)s
[2018-12-17 16:35:16 - INFO/sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:1154] {'cpe_0': 'cpe:/o:sun:solaris', 'cpe_1': 'cpe:/a:tritreal:ted_cde', 'cpe_2': 'cpe:/o:hp:hp-ux', 'active': 1}
[2018-12-17 16:35:16 - INFO/sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:1151] SELECT cpe.id AS cpe_id, cpe.active AS cpe_active, cpe.date_created AS cpe_date_created, cpe.timestamp AS cpe_timestamp, cpe.cpe_part_id AS cpe_cpe_part_id, cpe.device_id AS cpe_device_id, cpe.cpe AS cpe_cpe, cpe.match_nvd AS cpe_match_nvd
FROM cpe
WHERE (cpe.cpe LIKE %(cpe_0)s OR cpe.cpe LIKE %(cpe_1)s OR cpe.cpe LIKE %(cpe_2)s) AND cpe.active = %(active)s
[2018-12-17 16:35:16 - INFO/sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:1154] {'cpe_0': 'cpe:/a:hp:dtmail', 'cpe_1': 'cpe:/a:university_of_washington:pine', 'cpe_2': 'cpe:/o:sco:unixware', 'active': 1}
[2018-12-17 16:35:16 - ERROR/scap.abc:66] An error has occurred during task execution.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1127, in _execute_context
    context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 635, in _init_compiled
    grp, m in enumerate(parameters)]
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 635, in <listcomp>
    grp, m in enumerate(parameters)]
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 547, in construct_params
    % bindparam.key, code="cd3x")
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: A value is required for bind parameter 'cpe_2' (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/cd3x)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/scap/project/scap/abc.py", line 64, in run
    self(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/scap/project/scap/tasks.py", line 362, in __call__
    q.cve_insert_or_update(self.db, self.bakery, self.parse(name))
  File "/root/scap/project/scap/queries.py", line 148, in cve_insert_or_update
    cpes = list(cpe_filter(db, bakery, cpes))
  File "/root/scap/project/scap/queries.py", line 68, in cpe_filter
    **{'cpe_{}'.format(i): e for i, e in enumerate(products)}) \
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/baked.py", line 457, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/baked.py", line 364, in __iter__
    return q._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3018, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 948, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 269, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1060, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1132, in _execute_context
    None, None)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1413, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 265, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 248, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1127, in _execute_context
    context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 635, in _init_compiled
    grp, m in enumerate(parameters)]
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 635, in <listcomp>
    grp, m in enumerate(parameters)]
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/scap-TS2Ah8Sl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 547, in construct_params
    % bindparam.key, code="cd3x")
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind parameter 'cpe_2' [SQL: 'SELECT cpe.id AS cpe_id, cpe.active AS cpe_active, cpe.date_created AS cpe_date_created, cpe.timestamp AS cpe_timestamp, cpe.cpe_part_id AS cpe_cpe_part_id, cpe.device_id AS cpe_device_id, cpe.cpe AS cpe_cpe, cpe.match_nvd AS cpe_match_nvd \nFROM cpe \nWHERE (cpe.cpe LIKE %(cpe_0)s OR cpe.cpe LIKE %(cpe_1)s OR cpe.cpe LIKE %(cpe_2)s) AND cpe.active = %(active)s'] [parameters: [{'active': True, 'cpe_0': 'cpe:/a:university_of_washington:imap', 'cpe_1': 'cpe:/a:netscape:messaging_server'}]] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/cd3x)
```

As you can see, the function is called three times, the first two times it works without any issue (3 elements each time), and the third time it has only two elements and it expect a third element according to the error.

NB: The iterable can reach about 50 elements most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the observations 4. and 5. under ["Synopsis"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/baked.html#synopsis) in the baked queries documentation:

> 4. In the above code, even though our application may call upon `search_for_user()` many times, and even though within each invocation we build up an entirely new `BakedQuery` object, *all of the lambdas are only called once*. Each lambda is **never** called a second time for as long as this query is cached in the bakery.
> 5. The caching is achieved by storing references to the **lambda objects themselves** in order to formulate a cache key; that is, the fact that the Python interpreter assigns an in-Python identity to these functions is what determines how to identify the query on successive runs. For those invocations of `search_for_user()` where the `email` parameter is specified, the callable `lambda q: q.filter(User.email == bindparam('email'))` will be part of the cache key that’s retrieved; when `email` is `None`, this callable is not part of the cache key.

If you inspect your `cpe_filter()` function using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) you'll note that the lambda-functions are constants and so keep their identity between calls. As explained in the referenced documentation, SQLAlchemy caches queries based on those identities and calls

```
query += lambda y: y.filter(
    sa.or_(*[
        Cpe.cpe.like(sa.bindparam('cpe_{}'.format(i)))
        for i, _ in enumerate(iterable)
    ])
)
```

**only once**. In other words the placeholders will be set the first time you call `cpe_filter()`, based on `iterable`. They will be "reset" only when this query has been evicted from the cache.

The solution depends on your DBMS in use. For example Postgresql has the `ANY` array comparison that could be used:

```
query += lambda y: y.filter(Cpe.cpe.like(sa.any_(sa.bindparam('cpe'))))
```

and the parameter would be passed as

```
# This relies on Psycopg2's lists adaptation:
# http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#lists-adaptation
cpes = query(db).params(active=True, cpe=list(iterable)).all()
```

On MS SQL Server you could perhaps create a [full-text index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and use [`CONTAINS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
query += lambda y: y.filter(func.contains(Cpe.cpe, sa.bindparam('cpe')))
```

The bind param `cpe` should pass the search condition, which must be formed from `iterable`:

```
search_cond = " OR ".join(iterable)
cpes = query(db).params(active=True, cpe=search_cond).all()
```

This of course requires that the items in `iterable` are valid full-text search terms.

Comment: As we work MSSQL, as you said 'any' doesn't work. We keep investigating and will come back to you as soon as we find something interesting.

Comment: @Cybermate One option would be to use full-text search and a search condition that combines the values from `iterable` to prefix terms. That way you do not need a variable amount of placeholders, but 1. It also seems a bit cleaner in respect to having a bunch of `LIKE` combined with `OR`.